# Extract pandas column names based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Based on a pandas DataFrame `df`, I performed a ranking, which can be seen in `rank_df`.

Now, I would like to create a new DataFrame `results` that consists of three columns `["first", "second", "third"]`. This DataFrame should be filled with the respective column names of `rank_df`. For example, the first row of `results` could potentially comprise `['ticker_3', 'ticker_1', 'ticker_4']`. To put it differently, column `first` of `results` should always contain the column name of rank_df, which has the highest ranking. And so on...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)

cols = ["ticker_" + str(i + 1) for i in range(5)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 5), columns=cols)
df
```

Output:

```
   ticker_1  ticker_2  ticker_3  ticker_4  ticker_5
0  0.696469  0.286139  0.226851  0.551315  0.719469
1  0.423106  0.980764  0.684830  0.480932  0.392118
2  0.343178  0.729050  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044
```

Generate rank_df:

```
rank_df = df.rank(axis=1, method="first", ascending=False)
rank_df
```

Output:

```
   ticker_1  ticker_2  ticker_3  ticker_4  ticker_5
0       2.0       4.0       5.0       3.0       1.0
1       4.0       1.0       2.0       3.0       5.0
2       4.0       1.0       2.0       5.0       3.0
```

Need to generate results,

```
# NaNs in this final DataFrame needs to be filled with the respective column names
results = pd.DataFrame(None, index=rank_df.index, columns=["first", "second", "third"])
```

Comment: Can you add an example dataframe and an expected output

Comment: Yes please show us sample input and output. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC , you can try with `argsort`:

```
print(df)
    ticker_1  ticker_2  ticker_3  ticker_4  ticker_5
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763  0.544883  0.423655
1  0.645894  0.437587  0.891773  0.963663  0.383442
2  0.791725  0.528895  0.568045  0.925597  0.071036

results[:] = df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argsort(-df)][:,:3] #change 3 to n as reqd
print(results)
```

---

```
      first    second     third
0  ticker_2  ticker_3  ticker_1
1  ticker_4  ticker_3  ticker_1
2  ticker_4  ticker_1  ticker_3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using pandas reshaping:

```
rank_df.reset_index().melt('index').pivot('index', 'value', 'variable')\
       .rename(columns={1.0:'first', 2.0:'second', 3.0:'third'}).iloc[:, :3]
```

Output:

```
value     first    second     third
index                              
0      ticker_5  ticker_1  ticker_4
1      ticker_2  ticker_3  ticker_4
2      ticker_2  ticker_3  ticker_5
```